# Setting JFreeChart / Cewolf X Axis Interval

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, cewolf

I am trying to display some charts on a web app that has data for every minute.  The problem is when I try to view an hours worth of data (default) you just see a bunch of hash marks.  Is there a way to set the interval so that you it automatically sents 5  marks that display the date time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

Current:

http://img255.imageshack.us/my.php?image=minutes.jpg

Example X-axis Intervals: (have 60 minutes or more but only have 5 datetime tags for intervals)

http://img22.imageshack.us/my.php?image=newminutes.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you might try getting the DomainAxis from your plot and cast it to a DateAxis (Assuming that that's correct for your application).  Then set the the tickUnit property to something appropriate.  Maybe that'll at least point you in the right direction.  Good luck!